# Angular 6.1.9 nested routing to named outlets - 'Cannot match any routes' error

Tags: angular, angular6, router

I use *Angular 6.1.9* with its router module. It seems impossible for me to route/display a named outlet content.

When calling `<a [routerLink]="['', { outlets: { editArea: ['addRootPartner'] } }]">foo</a>` it crashes with:

> NavigationError(id: 2, url: '/overview/work/allPartners(editArea:addRootPartner)', error: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'addRootPartner')

---

My app structure is:

```
app.module
app-routing.module

workspace.module
workspace-routing.module
```

---

*app-routing*:

```
const rootAppRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',  redirectTo: 'overview', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'overview', loadChildren: './overview/workplace/workplace.module#WorkplaceModule' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Redirects to the `overview` which loads the `workplace` module.

*workplace-routing*:

```
const workplaceRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'work', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'work', component: WorkplaceComponent, children: [
    { path: 'allPartners', component: RootPartnersComponent },
    { path: 'childPartners', component: ChildPartnersComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'allPartners', pathMatch: 'full'}
  ]},
  { path: 'addRootPartner', component: AddRootPartnerComponent, outlet: 'editArea' }
];
```

Redirects to `work` which displays the `WorkplaceComponent`. Then it goes further to child `allPartners` which displays `RootPartnersComponent`.

---

In the code I use two `<router-outlet>`s. One is inside a component `app` module:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The second is in the `workplace` module, `WorkplaceComponent`:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="editArea"></router-outlet>
```

---

**What is wrong with this setup? Is there a technical restriction on usage of nested named outlets?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Okay, after a night spent with this mess, I found a solution.

---

First, the named outlet child routes don't work when defined under a parent with `path: ''`...

```
// the root redirect due to named outlets not being able to work as children of "path: ''"
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'work', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'work', component: WorkplaceComponent, children: [
   { path: '', component: RootPartnersComponent, outlet: 'displayArea' },
   { path: 'childPartners', component: ChildPartnersComponent, outlet: 'displayArea' },
   // child for edit area outlet
   { path: 'addRootPartner/:id', component: AddRootPartnerComponent, outlet: 'editArea' }
]}
```

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-router-nested-routes-and-nested-auxiliary-routes-build-a-menu-navigation-system/

---

Second issue was related to the router link. Apparently, you have to specify your parent route as the base of navigation. Thus navigation has to be done programmatically.

```
this.router.navigate([
  // NOTE: No relative-path navigation is required because we are accessing
  // the parent's "activatedRoute" instance. As such, this will be executed
  // as if we were doing this in the parent view component.
  {
    outlets: {
      editArea: ['addRootPartner']
    }
  }
],
  {
    relativeTo: this.activatedRoute.parent // <--- PARENT activated route.
  }
);
```

https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3351-closing-secondary-router-outlet-views-from-within-the-named-route-view-components-in-angular-4-4-4.htm

---

**Super late edit:**

The issue with `path: ''` might be caused by configuring this route as the first one.

> **The order of the routes in the configuration matters** and this is by design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes. In the configuration above, routes with a static path are listed first, followed by an empty path route, that matches the default route. The wildcard route comes last because it matches every URL and should be selected only if no other routes are matched first.

[angular.io/guide/router](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Comment: Hey I'd be curious to see a working exemple of your solution in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)

Comment: @Chax: It seems it works just a tiny bit different in stackblitz's Angular 7.0.1. Anyway, here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ffg92e

Comment: To add a little extra. It looks like you need to set `{relativeTo: this.route}` instead of 
`{relativeTo: this.route.parent}` when the named outlet is inside a child module (lazy loading in my case)